# Showing a stochastic process is previsible

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let
$$P(X_n = 1) = p_n, \ \ P(X_n = -1) = 1 - p_n.$$
Let $S_n$ be the sum of the $X_i$s so $S_n$ is a random walk. Let $Y_n = S_n ^2 -n.$ I am trying
to show that the process
$$\Psi = \frac{\Delta Y_n}{\Delta S_n}$$
is previsible/predictable. I have that
$$\Psi = \frac{\Delta Y_n}{\Delta S_n} = \frac{S_n ^2 - n - (S_{n-1} ^2 - (n-1))}{S_n - S_{n-1}} = \frac{2S_{n-1}X_n + X_n ^2 - 1}{X_n} = 2S_{n-1} + X_n - \frac{1}{X_n}.$$
I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Compute $X_n - \frac{1}{X_n}$ for $X_n = \pm 1$.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh it's always zero!